# How to do a binary filter on a BindingSource

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using the MySql .Net Connector binding the DataSet to a ComboBox.
I am trying to filter the dataset using a binary expression, and the results are always a null dataset.

```
this.customerBindingSource.Filter = "scale & 64";
this.customerBindingSource.Sort = "custid"; 
this.customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.requisitionDataSet11.customer);
```

if I change the filter to a basic = I get some of the results.

```
this.customerBindingSource.Filter = "scale = 64";
```

I am trying to achieve the equivalent of the sql this statement

```
SELECT * FROM customer where scale & 64 order by custid;
```

Comment: what about `"(scale & 64) <> 0"`?

Comment: I tried that also `(scale & 64) >0, (scale & 64)<>0`